# Add objects into array from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here i need to implement add objects into array for multiple row selections,here is my code

```
BOOL selectedRow

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if(selectedRow){
 UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
            NSLog(@"Airline cellTextC = %@",cellText);

if ([cellText isEqualToString:NameString]) {
                NSLog(@"Selected NameString Index = %@",indexes);

                [nameArray addObject:indexes];

            }else{
                NSLog(@"Unknown Selected Name");
            }

}
NSLog(@"Total Names  = %@",nameArray.description);

}
```

the above code one section and multiple rows is there ,if am selected a row `name string` should be add to the `Array` .It's working fine for only while am selecting one row.But i need add objects from multiple row selections.Can you please suggest me thanks .

Comment: Where is `nameArray` defined? Do you clear it or set it to a new instance?

Comment: Is it possible to re-organise your code so you can use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` and create the array of objects at the end?

Comment: As always, do not retrieve data from the cell (view), get it from the data source array (model)

Comment: you mean you need to have multiple row selection enable for the tableview ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update the data source of the Table View, and let the Table View Data source methods to update the Table View for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check if this can solve your problem:

```
[tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
```

Comment: please look at [answer]

Answer (score -1):

if you want to select Multiple rows and add objects to your array i suggest to create 2 `NSMutableArray` the first one contains all data and the other the selected rows data.

```
@property (strong , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myalldatatab;
@property (strong , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selecteddata;
```

then use didselectrowsatindexpath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath to change the mark

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

and you can get indexes of selected rows by calling this line :

```
NSArray *selectedCells = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

you can now iterate selected cells and add objects like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < [selectedCells count]; i++)
        {
[self.selecteddata addObject: [selectedCells objectAtIndex:i]]
}
```

Hope it help you :)) happy c0de !!